# back up fully Customized WordPress theme

Tags: backup

How to back up fully Customized WordPress theme and its page, post, full setting, contact form 7 data? So that we can install it directly on any other WordPress website.

Comment: the simplest to do is to copy the whole website. read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice to backup whole theme and data, first you need to export the XML file.

Login to WordPress Dashboard > Tools > Export

[image: export-xml]

Every theme save their options differently, You can use third party plugin which favors your theme to export the settings.